# Is there a way to prevent access to the Preferences menu in Safari in OS X?

Tags: macos, safari, preferences

I am looking for a way to deny the access to the Preferences settings of Safari in OS X. Similar (hidden) options are already available for the Finder, where you can hide the preferences menu with the following command:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder ProhibitFinderPreferences -bool true
```

I am asking, because I want to prevent any changes within the Extensions section in Safari by family members.

Comment: Giving them their own account might be easier here

Comment: that is one possibility, but i need only one user account for my purpose.

Comment: If everybody uses the same admin account, everybody has the same admin privileges, therefore anything you do can be undone by any other user. The only real way to limit what a user does is to not give them an admin account.

Comment: the question is however, if a non-admin account in osx will deny the access to the settings of safari? somehow, i doubt it :/